# Laravel basic MVC - setting values in a controller and pass it to a view

Tags: php, laravel

O.k. I just set up Laravel and I'm missing a basic concept.

**Route**

```php
Route::get('controllertest', 'ControllerTest@getIndex');
```

**Controller**

```php
public function getIndex()
{
    return View::make('test_controller');
}
```

**View**

```php
<title>{{ $title }}</title>
```

I've tried everything and I can't get a variable to pass from the controller to the view.

Everything works but my title is still `{{ $title }}`

Yes, this is basic stuff, but how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variables to your views in the following way:

```php
public function getIndex() {
    return View::make('test_controller', [
        'title' => 'Title Value'
    ]);
}
```

An alternative is to use the following syntax:

```php
public function getIndex() {
    return View::make('test_controller')->with('title', 'Title Value');
}
```

Check their [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views) for more detail.

Comment: Neither does the second...no idea what's up.

Comment: What error do you get? Is it even displaying your view? Try removing the variable from your view and add some static HTML to test whether it is displaying.

Comment: @user3096851 Also, "my title is still `{{ $title }}`". Are you saying that it's actually outputting "{{ $title }}" into the HTML?

Comment: I've tried both {{$title}} and {{title}}, neither work...so weird, I know.

Comment: @user3096851 If you answer the questions in my previous comments, I might be able to help you :P

Comment: No error, the display works with both, but it doesn't display the value.

Comment: @user3096851 What does it display instead? Nothing? Or "{{ $title }}"?

Comment: {{ $title }} or {{title}} I've added static html and it works.

Comment: @user3096851 That sounds like you're not using a [Blade](http://laravel.com/docs/templates) file. Your view's file should be named `test_controller.blade.php`.

Comment: You are the man or woman or whatever. Thank you so much. This works.

Comment: @user3096851 I'm glad I could help :). You should definitely have a look around their [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/quick#creating-a-view), it's really helpful. Also, accept and/or vote up my answer if it provided a solution to the question you posed (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).